# Amenability of $l^\infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, amenability

I'm working on the amenability of some Banach algebras, and I'm wondering why  $l^\infty$ is amenable ? Does any one has any idea how to start ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As indicated in the answer below: see Johnson's 1972 monograph, or the proof in Bonsall and Duncan's book

Comment: This question admits an easy answer if you know the right references, so I am voting to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, commutative $C^\ast$-algebras are amenable. See [*A new proof of the amenability of $C(X)$*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0004972709001063) by Mortaza Abtahi and Yong Zhang (Bulletin of the Australian Mathematical Society, Volume 81, Issue 3, June 2010, pages 414-417).

Comment: Can we prove it using the definition only ? Can we prove the existence of a bouded approximate diagonal for $l^\infty$

Comment: @user128591 Please see the references mentioned in my comment above

Answer (score 0):

$l^\infty$ is a $C^*$-algebra, in fact a von Neumann algebra. For these algebras, there are many equivalent definitions of amenability. For example, for finite von Neumann algebras one such example is the existence of a Hilbert bi-module $\mathcal{H}$ and a sequence of vector $\{\xi_i\}$ such that $\|a\xi_i-\xi_ia\|_2\rightarrow 0$, for all $a$ in the algebra. You can take the usual representation of $l^\infty$ on $l^2$ by multiplication (since $l^\infty$ is a abelian this actually make it into a bimodule and the above convergence is trivial since it is abelian.

Comment: With all due respect, this is massive overkill. Also the "correct" notion of amenability for a von Neumann algebra is not the same as saying its underlying Cstar-algebra is amenable in the Banach-algebraic sense

Comment: E.g. a two-one factor is never amenable as a Banach algebra